# Golang revel+mgo - no data returned when struct variables having lowercase names

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mgo, revel

This is my struct type

```
type Category struct {
    Name string     `bson:"listName"`
    Slug string     `bson:"slug"`
}
```

used with the following function to return all results from a mongo collection -

```
func GetCategories(s *mgo.Session) []Category {
    var results []Category
    Collection(s).Find(bson.M{}).All(&results)
    return results
}
```

The problem is that the field names in my db have names starting in lowercase but the Golang struct returns null when I try to use variable names starting with lower case. For e.g. this returns a JSON with corresponding fields empty -

```
type Category struct {
    listName string `bson:"listName"`
    slug string     `bson:"slug"`
}
```

I'm actually porting a Meteor based API to Golang and a lot of products currently using the API rely on those field names like they are in the db!
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Also, please do not ignore errors.  Collection(s).Find(bson.M{}).All(&results) should check for the returned value ( type error ) to be nil.

https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your fields visible for [mgos bson Unmarshall](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Unmarshal) by naming them with a starting capital letter. You also need to map to the appropiates json/bson field names

```
type Category struct {
    ListName string      `json:"listName" bson:"listName"`
    Slug string          `json:"slug"     bson:"slug"`
}
```

Comment: This -
type Category struct {
 ListName string      `bson:"listName"`
 Slug string              `bson:"slug"`
}
Returns this -
{
    "ListName": "Trimmer/Epilator",
    "Slug": "trimmer"
  },

Whereas, this - 
type Category struct {
 ListName string      `json:"listName"`
 Slug string              `json:"slug"`
}
Returns this - 
{"listName": "",
    "slug": "trimmer"
  },
Which is actually closer to what I'd want. I want the field names to be there in the json just as they are.

Comment: add ```bson:"listName" json:"listName"```

Comment: Please include this in the answer and I can mark it as correct! You're awesome!